# Calling an subview from a button: application closes

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, console, uibutton, subview

While my application launches like normal and has no errors, when I attempt to click a button to show another view, the application closes.
On the debugger console, this is the the display:

```
"SEM2REDO[13487:b603] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x4ea5be0>"
```

then the second time you click it, this appears, and then the application cancels.

```
2012-01-24 11:46:37.549 SEM2REDO[13591:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/margueriteoquinn/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/F2B86CC5-C700-414E-9030-17E94535EB1A/SEM2REDO.app> (loaded)' with name 'SelectView''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc95a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f1d313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d81ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d81e6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x004b40fa -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2024
    5   UIKit                               0x004b5ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    6   UIKit                               0x0036b628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    7   UIKit                               0x00369134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    8   UIKit                               0x0036900e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    9   UIKit                               0x00367482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    10  UIKit                               0x00377f25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    11  UIKit                               0x00376555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    12  UIKit                               0x00377870 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    13  UIKit                               0x0037232a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    14  UIKit                               0x00379562 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    15  UIKit                               0x003721c4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    16  SEM2REDO                            0x00002590 -[SEM2REDOViewController chooseFirstMeeting:] + 252
    17  UIKit                               0x002b94fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    18  UIKit                               0x00349799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    19  UIKit                               0x0034bc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    20  UIKit                               0x0034a7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    21  UIKit                               0x002ddded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    22  UIKit                               0x002bec37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    23  UIKit                               0x002c3f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x01721992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00daa944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0acf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00d07f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00d07840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00d07761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x017201c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x01720289 GSEventRun + 115
    32  UIKit                               0x002c7c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    33  SEM2REDO                            0x00001a70 main + 102
    34  SEM2REDO                            0x00001a01 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I have no idea what this means, but I really need some help.  Here is some helpful delegate method that I have implemented

```
@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    SEM2REDOViewController  *firstController = [[SEM2REDOViewController alloc]
                                            initWithNibName:@"SEM2REDOViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController  *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                              initWithRootViewController:firstController];

    [self setNavController:navigationController];
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    [navigationController release];
    [firstController release];  

    return YES;
```

}

and this is the method in my SEM2REDOViewController to display the second view

```
- (IBAction)chooseFirstMeeting:(id)sender {     
    SelectRotationController *selectView = [[SelectRotationController alloc] 
                                            initWithNibName:@"SelectView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [selectView.navigationItem setTitle:@"Select First Meeting"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectRotationController animated:YES];
    self.selectRotationController = selectView; 
    [selectView release];
}
```

I'm sorry if this is an easy question: I am a highschooler attempting to do an independent study on programming so ANY help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your second block of code is the same as the first one. Do you want to edit that? Also, use code formatting -- just highlight the code and then select the curly braces at the top of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

SEM2REDOViewController *firstController = [[SEM2REDOViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SEM2REDOViewController" bundle:nil]; UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstController];

[self setNavController:navigationController];
 [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[navigationController release]; [firstController release];

return YES;
```

**Change it to**

```
SEM2REDOViewController *firstController = [[[SEM2REDOViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SEM2REDOViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: firstController]autorelease];

 [window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

This will do solve your issue..if you have any problem understanding something let me know.

Comment: try changing the line [window addSubview.... to     self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

Comment: try breakpointing through your code.. check which line does it successfully passes and on which line it crashes?

Comment: that was all that it said under the breakpoint... I don't know what any of it means.

Comment: check any youtube tutorial for Xcode debugging..will be very helpful to you long down the road..i cannot make you understand how to debug here and also you don't have enough reputation that we could chat in the chat room to solve your problem easily..so check a tutorial and then try debugging through the code..check again on which line it crashes..

Comment: Thanks! I updated my interface (sometimes it doesn't automatically read class files) and now it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are releasing your navigation controller and then attempting to add a view controller to it.